# Use number from input to access array position

Tags: ruby

EDIT :  First part removed i found the answer.

I have the following problem : im reading a number from the input and trying to use that number to access a given array position. I get the following results

```
value #=> "0"
value.to_i #=> 0
myArray[0] #=> MyObject
myArray[value.to_i] #=> nil
```

Comment: can you post an example of myArray?
"0".to_i == 0 #=> true

Comment: -1 for not including reproducible code.

Answer (score 4):

That works for me.

```
irb(main):012:0> myArray = ['first']
=> ["first"]
irb(main):013:0> value = '0'
=> "0"
irb(main):014:0> myArray[value.to_i]
=> "first"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `myArray[Integer(value)]` (although `value.to_i` works for me as well):

```
>> value = "0"
=> "0"
>> myArray = ["a", "b"]
=> ["a", "b"]
>> myArray[0]
=> "a"
>> myArray[Integer(value)]
=> "a"
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all your replies, i was trying to access and array inside a class variable with:

```
@myclass.myarray[value]
```

when i made a getter method and accessed myarray inside the object the error disappeared. If anyone can explain this behavior please let me know